# Inline elements like span without default styling

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an inline element to my page. It should behave exactly like span i.e. not introduce any default styling of it's own..I want to just be able to refer this element in my JS (using id).
Please help me suggest some style(less) elements like span.

Comment: Nothing (not even `span`) lacks default styles (although `span`'s defaults are pretty neutral).

Comment: I cannot use span bcoz it has some styling applied in CSS and I cannot change that since it is used in multiple places...

Comment: @testndtv - Can't you define another class which undoes the existing styling and apply that to `span` elements that shouldn't have it?

Comment: I am avoiding undoing the styling which gets applied to CSS, as there are a lot of them..So looking for some straightforward way of doing it...like some basic inline element like span without any default styling of it's own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use createElement() in JavaScript

```
<script>
    var newElement = document.createElement('newElement');
    newElement.setAttribute('id', 'newElementId');
    var oldElement = document.getElementById('element');
    oldElement.appendChild(newElement);
</script>

<div id="element"></div>
```

That should add a new element type, "newElement"

Comment: why -1? this is right answer, in IE7 and below we should define new elements with JavaScript. this question need an element without default style and `newElement` is new element without style

Answer (score 3):

Why not just add some extra css as mentioned by @James Allardice that removes old css and or applies new styling.

Html:

```
<span>My Super Cool Span</span>

<span id="MySpan>My Super Cool Span With An ID </span>
```

css:

```
span {
     width:100px;
}

span #MySpan{
     width: auto; // resetting width
     // Reset css or apply new styling
}
```

By doing this only spans with id `MySpan` will use your new styling or have their styles reset.

Look at css attributes on www.w3schools.com to find out their defaults values.

Then you can refer to MySpan in javascript by doing:

```
document.getElementById('MySpan')
```

Or in jquery by doing:

```
$("#MySpan")
```